# Moongoose schema usage for update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my schema

```
var DrivingSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  permalink: {type: String, required: true},
  phone: {type: Number, required: true},
  mobile: {type: Number},
  bike: {type: Boolean, default: false }    
});
```

I used this schema for adding data. It worked fine.

But when I have to update data, I couldn't use this schema because it gave new `_id`. Here is my controller for update.

```
DriveModel.findOne({permalink: permalink}, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        var newData = new DriveModel({
            title: title,
            phone: phone,
            mobile: mobile,
            bike: bike});
        DriveModel.update({_id:data._id}, newData, function(err, result) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            else{res.redirect('/centres/'+permalink);}                
        });
});
```

This controller didn't work because of `_id` conflict. [Mongoose Schema documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) suggests to use `_id: false` in schema but it again works for update not for new insertion of data. Now, how could I solve this issue? Do I have to build another schema just for update or is there anyway to handle with same schema?

Comment: When you want to update? When you create the element, you can send back to the client the added element with the _id. Then the update is much easier. I only used Mean.js, Mean.js has an example of articles. At https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/articles/server/controllers/articles.server.controller.js  you can check the function exports.create and exports.update. And at https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/articles/server/models/article.server.model.js you can check the model. I dont have time now for more i hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   var elements = {"title": title, "phone": phone, "mobile": mobile, "bike": bike};

    DriveModel.findOne({"permalink": permalink}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.end(err);
        }

        for(elem in elements) {
            data[elem] = elements[elem];
        }

        data.save(function(err, place) {
            if(err) {
                res.end(err);
            } else {
                res.redirect('/centres/'+permalink);
            }
        });

    });
```